# G++ __FUNCTION__ on method's with class name?

Tags: function, compilation, g++, constants

Is there a compile-time constant like __FUNCTION__ or __func__ that includes for class methods also the class name?

For example for a method named **foo** in class **Bar** it should not expand to *foo* but to *Bar::foo*.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, with GCC or Clang you can use the non-standard extension `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` which gives the full signature e.g. `void Bar::foo(int)`

See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html